# memory location calculation

Tags: memory, assembly

The question is as follow :
A microcomputer has memory locations from 00000h to FFFFFh. Each memory
location stores 1 byte. In decimal, how many bytes can the microcomputer store in its
memory? How many Kilobytes is this?

Answer:
It requires two 2Kbytes of RAM and 512 bytes
of PROM.

I try to calculate myself before reviewing the answer,and find out that it is not same,till now i still don't understand why this is the answer,anyone may give me some help??Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 00000h to FFFFFh, this represents 100,000h memory locations, hence 100,000h bytes. 10h^5 (hex) is 16^5 (decimal).

16^5 = (2^4)^5 = 2^20 = (1024)^2 = 1 M = 1024 K.

Conclusion: this processor can *address* one megabyte of memory.

Obviously, less than one megabyte is installed on this microcomputer, and not all of the installed memory is RAM. But you can't deduce this from the amount of *addressable* memory.

Comment: Hello ChrisJ,mind explain your steps in more detail,I've problem trying to follow what you explained,thanks

Comment: Besides why say it is 1000,000 bytes?? I thought it has memory location 16^5 which is equal to 1048576

Comment: I said 1 M, not 1,000,000. In computer science, 1 M is usually 1024^2, not 1000^2. What reasoning step is problematic for you?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is clearly the answer to another question and not this one.

Comment: Is there any book recommended to study this kind of mathematical stuff for computer??

Comment: I think any book in computer science starts out with basic arithmetic.